# the html 5 boilerplate extension in vs code showes me a message and it is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, runtime-error, vscode-extensions

I am new to this world, and I just downloaded VS code, and installed some extensions and some of them does not work my main problem is the HTML5 boilerplate extension is not working it is showing me on the runtime status bar the next message "unknown language in 'contributes.HTML5-boilerplate.language'. provided value: njk" I don't know what to do please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should try to set VS Code to the English language. I believe the error means that the HTML5 boilerplate extension doesn't recognise the language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. It was showing an annoying message 'Waiting for an HTML File' in the VScode status bar. I couldn't fix the issue.

But I right clicked on that message and unchecked 'Extension status' and that message is not showing anymore on the status bar atleast.